# I want to send email using java program. I am getting the excetion as below

Tags: java, email

I'm getting this exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: server.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: server.gmail.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1280)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.SimpleSendEmail.main(SimpleSendEmail.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: server.gmail.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 7 more
```

I have included the required jar files also.
Please help me solve this exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `smtp.gmail.com` as your host.

Comment: By using smtp.gmail.com Im getiing the exception..java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: You're going to have to check why your connection is timing out. Did you set your mail port to gmail's SSL port which is 465? Did you set the SSL/AUTH requirement to YES?

Answer (score 0):

your smtp host is obviously wrong

Try only `smtp.gmail.com`